# In Confluence, how do I create a permanant link to a specific version of a page when that page is the current version?

Tags: confluence

We use Confluence for documenting business specific processes.

Say today (March 11th) I edit a page in Confluence and the new page is version 2.  I need to store a link to that page in a report for auditing purposes.  I know how to get a link (Tools/Link to this Page...) and the saved link looks like this "http://wiki/display/OneSource/EEPROM".  All seems well and good.

Now next month I need to update the page so I create version 3.

When I return to the March report and select the link I saved, version 3 loads, not version 2 as I expected.

Not to worry as I see that I can get a different link to store in my report.  From the history page I get this link to the current page (http://wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=21364790).  However, it yields the same result.  After editing the page to create version 3, my saved link now points to the version 3 and not to version 2 as expected.

How do I get a link to version 2 for my report that will always point to version 2 when version 2 is also the current version?

TIA,

Michael

Comment: Ticket raised with Atlassian:
https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CONF-34886

Comment: See answer by @madel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, you can't without a custom plugin to handle links with versions. Confluence will *always* use the pageId of the *original* page as the latest version and insert a new pageId for historical versions as they are created. For example, your current page has pageId 21364790 and version 2; editing the page creates a new pageId 21364791 as a copy of the previous version, and updates 21364790 with your changes. This means that there is no way to predict what the pageId of a historical version will be when it is currently the latest version.

I see two solutions. The more elegant solution is to make a plugin providing a copy of the XWork viewpage action, and giving it a version parameter. You could then access the correct version using a URL like `http://wiki/pages/myviewpage.action?pageId=21364790&version=2`. The ugly hack solution is to double-up your edits, so you can be sure of what the correct historical pageId will be.

Comment: Thanks, that is pretty much whar we thought.  We are exploring the plugin option.

Answer (score 11):

You can do it manually by specifying the version of the page in URL - `http://wiki/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=21364790&pageVersion=1`

But even better to have something similar to https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.k15t.scroll.scroll-versions

Comment: What makes things even more confusing is that there seem to be two types of pageid: old for older versions, when you navigate history, and one for the latest revision of the page. This method works with the current revision type of version. Also it works with the full text URL form. The latest version of page id can be found on the page history.

Answer (score 3):

[Page version link plugin](https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/43314)

[image]

> This plugin adds to a header of every page the link, referring to the
>   displayed version of the page regardless of any future content
>   updates.

Is it what you need?

Answer (score 0):

The Page version link plugin no longer exists for newer confluence versions.
But I've found the [Scroll Versions Plugin](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.k15t.scroll.scroll-versions) which supports the link to a specific version of a page.

Additionally it has many more features like editing multiple versions of a page in a single space and publishing all/selected pages of a specific versions when you have finished it.

Answer (score 0):

From  the ... Go to the page history. Right click on the specific version link -> copy link address

[image]

Note : the first link is a permanent link to the current version.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Tierry Dalon suggestion:

If you only copy link and paste to confluence (as Tierry Dalon suggests), confl will transform the link to most current page (silly), which you do not want.

You can workaround this transformation by using the Insert link macro (ctrl+k) and paste link to both text and hyperlik field. this will fix your link to version

[dialog for edditing link insertion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Fc9A.png)